# Displaying large blocks of text - Swift

Tags: swift, text

I have quite a lot of text to display on different pages in my app and am wondering if there are any best practices to deal with this.

Currently considering using a WebView and calling a local html file. Seems to be the only way to format easily without doing it programmatically.

New at this so any thoughts, ideas, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So, my question is - how do I display large blocks of text in my app using Swift?

Comment: Could you provide some additional information? Should it work like book reading application (then take a look at UIPageViewController) or maybe you want those pages to scroll almost infinitely with a lot of single paragraph text?

Comment: Yes, I was considering that as I have 4 pages and I wanted to avoid using a View Controller for each page though the only tutorial I've found uses ImageView on the storyboard and I can't seem to convert it to either TextView or WebView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard text display interface object for big chunks of text (i.e. scrollable) is UITextView.

You can write your text as HTML, just as you are doing now, and convert it to an NSAttributedString for display in the UITextView. Or you could store it as an RTF document and, again, convert it to an NSAttributedString.

Comment: Didn't know you could write text as HTML, that's good to know. Not sure I am advanced enough yet to work out how to convert that to an NSAttributedString though will give it a shot and get back to you if I have problems.

Comment: Example code of fetching an RTF document and converting it to NSAttributedString: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p504RTFImportTest/RTFImportTest/ViewController.swift HTML (if you decide to use that) is parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this in my app. You can use the 'UITextView' object which you can easily format with font size etc. I was planning to use webview in my app too in order to display text but it won't feel as *native* and if you are pulling it in from an HTML file stored online, there will be a delay of about a second.

Comment: Yes, that delay is annoying, would definitely prefer a more native feel. So you have to format the UITextView programmatically presumably. Still very new at this...

Comment: There's not a whole lot of flexibility there though, is there. All text has to be the same size, font etc. I thought that was mainly to format input text.

Comment: Thats all you'll get with UITextView. As others have suggested though you can pull from RTF or HTML into a UITextView and use your own formatting - there will be a slight delay though.

Comment: Ok, I'll give all the suggestions a try and see which works best for me. Thanks for your help.